# Move iTunes to a new computer

Tags: itunes

I have a backup of my music folder and my iTunes files and I want to restore it on a new computer which would be easy enough except this time I have an SSD drive on C: so I want the music and data on D:. Any chance this is easy?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, here is what I ended up doing. Note that on the computer that died I had the "Keep iTunes Media folder Organized" and "Copy files to iTunes Media folder when adding to library" checked already because, well, I wanted all the media in one place so it was easy to backup.

- Copy the files from backup to the drive you want them on (long before there was an iTunes I've stored my music right off the root in c:\mp3z\ but in this case I wanted them at d:\mp3z\ since the c drive is a tiny SSD drive . . . in general I don't like to trap the files in a particular login)
- Install iTunes (64-bit in my case)
- Start iTunes and go to preferences and set it up so the media folder is d:\mp3z\iTunes (same path as my old machine except for the d drive instead)
- Close iTunes and copy all the old iTunes library files from backup to C:\Users\\Music\iTunes (that includes iTunes Music Library.xml, iTunes Library.itl, iTunes Library Genius.itdb and iTunes Library Extras.itdb)
- Use an app like [Search and Replace](http://www.funduc.com/search_replace.htm) on "iTunes Music Library.xml" to replace all instances of "file://localhost/C" with "file://localhost/D". I tired in Notepad and Aptana and they both locked up and I had to start over. Search and Replace did all 8000 changes in 3 seconds.
- That's it! I went to podcasts and clicked refresh to get the latest and plugged in my iPod and later iPad to sync them up! Note however I had to "authorize" this new computer. Now I need to figure out how to "unauthorize" the old computer without actually having the old computer available. New Question!

Sheldon

Answer (score 3):

this is what you can do in general. the easiet way is to just copy all folder in D: and drag all folder to your itunes

1- If you are a Windows user and don’t want to go through all of this hacking, you can buy [iTunes Transfer software](http://www.transfermymusic.com/transfer-itunes-software/) at my partner site. It will help you back up your library – with playlists – and transfer it to your other computer.

2- If you’re trying to transfer music from your iPod to your computer, unfortunately, Apple won’t let you do this freely, but you can buy [iPod to Computer software for PC](http://www.transfermymusic.com/ipod-to-computer-software-pc/) (free trial download), or [iPod to Computer software for Mac](http://www.transfermymusic.com/ipod-to-computer-software-mac/) at my partner site that will allow you to do this.

3-if you just have the hard drive of your old PC, [Ben has shared with us](http://www.kadavy.net/blog/posts/transfer-itunes-library/#comment-514) how to make the transfer

4-if you aren’t keen on messing with XML files – and play count isn’t important to you - [Oden has a simple process](http://www.kadavy.net/blog/posts/transfer-itunes-library/#comment-483), involving smart playlists, for retaining song ratings when you transfer your iTunes library.

5- [Collin has a simple way](http://www.kadavy.net/blog/posts/transfer-itunes-library/#comment-491) to find out those duplicate songs that you may end up with when transferring your catalog.

6-[Aaron devised a clever way](http://www.kadavy.net/blog/posts/transfer-itunes-library/#comment-493) to transfer while retaining playlists in your collection.

7- If you are transferring between Macs, [pbaron has a method](http://www.kadavy.net/blog/posts/transfer-itunes-library/#comment-500) involving [FireWire mode](http://www.kadavy.net/blog/archive/2004/11/make_your_mac_a.php).

this is the [source](http://www.kadavy.net/blog/posts/transfer-itunes-library/).

Answer (score 1):

Here are two options, I'm sure there are others.

- [How to move your iTunes library to an external drive](http://lifehacker.com/238296/ultranewb--how-to-move-your-itunes-library-to-an-external-drive)
- [Move Your iTunes Library To Another Computer With iTunes 9 Home Sharing](http://www.lifehacker.com.au/2010/03/move-your-itunes-library-to-another-computer-with-itunes-9-home-sharing/)